# Freeform Mailchimp List - Target

Tags: plugin-freeform

using Freeform Pro, set mailchimp key, how do I target a specific list on mailchimp to send and config with please?

Answer (score 2):

Add the mailing list "field" in the form you want by dragging it from the left sidebar to the form. 
Click on the field when it's added. 
In the right sidebar, change the dropdown field "Mailing Lists" to the list you want.